# Android: Use icon as back button without reloading previous activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have the following code to enable to home button to act as a back button.  The problem I'm facing is from this activity if I use the real back button it simply goes back to the previous activity just as I left it.  If I use the home button it's reloading the page so I lose what was previously done to it.  I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.census_management_search, menu);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CensusManagementActivity.class);
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of `Intent` and `NavUtils` try using `onBackPressed()` method.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is better to call [`onBackPressed()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.onBackPressed%28%29) because it checks fragments' back stack and if it is empty calls `finish()`

Comment: Thanks Perfectly working without reload activity again onCreate() method calling.

Answer (score 2):

The Home/Up button is supposed to reload the new activity. However, if you want to emulate the back button functionality, you can call `finish()` to return to the previous activity:

```
 case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
        return true;
```

Comment: `finish()` will always close the current activity, while `onBackPressed()` handles if there are `Fragment`s on the back stack, reversing those operations first before closing the Activity.

Comment: I tried both onBackPressed() and finish() and they are reloading my previous activity. Previous activity uses fragments and it refreshes each time I press back icon. If I click on back button on phone it works fine.

Comment: I found out my error was using ``R.id.home`` instead of ``android.R.id.home``